# If you only have a single write thread, do you ever need special concurrency?

Tags: java, concurrency

Assuming:

1. There is only one specific thread that ever sets a certain reference field (not a long or double, so writes to it are atomic)
2. There are any number of threads that might read that same field
3. Slightly stale reads are acceptable (up to a few seconds)

In this scenario, do you need volatile or AtomicReference or anything like that?

[This article](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/single-writer-principle.html) states:

> Memory barriers are not required if you adhere strictly to the single writer principle.

Which seems to suggest that in the case I'm describing, you really don't need to do anything special.

So, here's a test I ran with curious results:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class ThreadTest {
    int onlyWrittenByMain = 0;
    int onlyWrittenByThread = 0;

    @Test
    public void testThread() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                do {
                    onlyWrittenByThread++;
                } while (onlyWrittenByMain < 10 || onlyWrittenByThread < 10);
                System.out.println("thread done");
            }
        });
        newThread.start();

        do {
            onlyWrittenByMain++;
            // Thread.yield();
            // System.out.println("test");
            // new Random().nextInt();
        } while (onlyWrittenByThread < 10);
        System.out.println("main done");
    }
}
```

Sometimes running this will output "thread done" and then hang forever. Sometimes it does complete. So the thread sees the changes the main thread makes, but apparently main doesn't always see the change that the thread makes?

If I put the system out in, or the Thread.yield, or the random call, or make onlyWrittenByThread volatile, it completes every time (tried about 10+ times).

Does that mean that the blog post I reference above is incorrect? That you do have to have a memory barrier even in the single writer scenario?

No one quite answered this question so I think I'll guess that it's likely correct that a memory barrier is not required, but without something to create the happens-before relationship, the java compiler and hotspot can do optimizations (eg. hoisting) that will make it not do what one wants.

Comment: You still have to worry about an incomplete write, i.e. reading your variable when it's been only partially written. If writes are atomic, you're ok.

Comment: You _do_ need at least `volatile`. There are no guarantees that a write to a non volatile variable by one thread will _ever_ be visible by other threads. `volatile` guarantees this!

Comment: @fge, can you provide any definitive documentation for that? I'm trying to read through chapter 17 of the spec, but I'm not seeing what supports your claim. Though, perhaps it's the lack of a statement refuting it is the point.

Comment: @taotree my documentation is [this](http://jcip.net/)

Comment: As @fge states `volatile`, also as linked in later comment get the JCIP book.

Comment: Voted your Q up because this reminded me of the same mistake I made some weeks ago.... and I think I have to fix my app to use volatile.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is caching on a multicore system - without something like volatile forcing the happens-before relationship (memory-barrier stuff) you could have your writer thread writing to a copy of the variable in cache on its core and all your reader threads reading another copy of the variable on another core. The other issue is atomicity, which another answer addresses.

Comment: The situation you describe is about the staleness of the data, isn't it? If the reader thread reads the data once every second, isn't it guaranteed to eventually see the value that the writer thread wrote at some point?

Comment: It depends on the memory consistency model of the underlying machine... it's not likely to be an issue. The point is that the JLS doesn't specify that it has to - it's the reason for the happens-before relationship in the JMM.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in your code is not so much about what the CPU will do but what the JVM will do with it: you have a high risk of variable hoisting. What that means is that the JMM (Java Memory Model) allows a JVM to rewrite:

```
public void run() {
    do {
        onlyWrittenByThread++;
    } while (onlyWrittenByMain < 10 || onlyWrittenByThread < 10);
    System.out.println("thread done");
}
```

as this other piece of code (notice the local variables):

```
public void run() {
    int localA = onlyWrittenByMain;
    int localB = onlyWrittenByThread;
    do {
        localB ++;
    } while (localA < 10 || localB < 10);
    System.out.println("thread done");
}
```

It happens that this is a fairly common optimisation made by hotpost. In your case, once that optimisation is made (probably not straight away when you call that method but after a few milliseconds), whatever you do in other threads will **never** be visible from that thread.

Comment: Right, that's what I was guessing, too. The volatile keyword would preclude that optimization.

Comment: To preclude hoisting, you need some form of synchronization. In that case, volatile variables would probably be the cheapest way.

Answer (score 1):

It is needed because changes on the read field may not be visible to reader threads.You should create a happens before relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you misunderstood the words you quoted from Martin's blog. On a x86/64 hardware you could use Atomic*.lazySet to gain much more performance than 'volatile' because it provides store-store barrier which is much cheaper than the store-load barrier.
As far as I understand, you should use AtomicLong instead and use lazySet to guarantee the codes are not reordered.

Please refer to this article for more details:
http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.com/2012/12/atomiclazyset-is-performance-win-for.html